# Nodemon App Crashed with No TypeError - Need Help Resolving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemon

when i am creating my project it gives an error of nodemon crashed but their is no typeError

[this is an error] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNFy9.png)[nodemon version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwRqC.png)
I am currently working on a project, and I'm encountering an issue with nodemon that I'm struggling to resolve. When attempting to run my project, nodemon crashes, but I'm not seeing any TypeError in the error message.
[nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNFy9.png)

[nodemon version] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwRqC.png)

Details:

I've checked for syntax errors and other common issues in my code, but I couldn't find anything that would cause a crash.
All dependencies are up to date, and I've confirmed this by running npm install.
I've also tried running the application directly with node to see if the issue persists without nodemon, but the crash still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to your MongoDB connection settings, please check the
connection  settings again
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password